# Cannot autowire service ... Though service parameter is configure

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have a problem autowiring some parameters in services config.

I can't `clear:cache` because it triggers the error so I don't think it is a cache issue.
And I have copy/paste all my files into a whole new Symfony project and still got the same problem.

This is my services.yaml

```
#config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.medipim_api_key_value: '%env(resolve:MEDIPIM_API_KEY)%'
    app.medipim_api_key_id: 326
services:
    [6 lines ...]
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: 
    '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    App\Services\MedipimApi:
        arguments:
            $medipim_api_key_id: '%app.medipim_api_key_id%'
            $medipim_api_key_value: '%app.medipim_api_key_value%'
   [10 lines ...]
```

This is my services :

```
#src/Services/MedipimApi.php
class MedipimApi
{

    const FILTER_CNK_AND_ACTIVE = 'filter_cnk_and_active';

    /**
     * @var MedipimApiV3Client
     */
    private MedipimApiV3Client $medipimApiV3Client;

    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    /**
     * MedipimApi constructor.
     * @param string $medipim_api_key_id API key id for Medipim API call
     * @param string $medipim_api_key_value Api key (secret) value for Medipim API call
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator TranslatorInterface object for I18N purpose
     */
    public function __construct(string $medipim_api_key_id, string $medipim_api_key_value, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->medipimApiV3Client = new MedipimApiV3Client($medipim_api_key_id, $medipim_api_key_value);
    }
....
```

When I try to call this service, I got this error :

> Cannot autowire service "App\Services\MedipimApi": argument
> "$medipim_api_key_id" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted
> "string", you should configure its value explicitly.

It is working only when I copy the value of `services.yaml` and paste it into my `services_env.yaml` (where env is my current environment).

```
#config/services_dev.yaml
parameters:
    app.medipim_api_key_value: '%env(resolve:MEDIPIM_API_KEY)%'
    app.medipim_api_key_id: 326
services:
    [6 lines ...]
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude:  '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    App\Services\MedipimApi:
        arguments:
            $medipim_api_key_id: '%app.medipim_api_key_id%'
            $medipim_api_key_value: '%app.medipim_api_key_value%'
   [10 lines ...]
```

Now it works!

Why did that work?

Symfony is suppose to load file as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/configuration/configuration_organization.html) :

> For the dev environment, Symfony loads the following config files and
> directories and in this order:
>
> - config/packages/*
> - config/packages/dev/*
> - config/services.yaml
> - config/services_dev.yaml

What did I miss?

**EDIT**

My kernel class looks right. It is loading services.yaml and then services_env.yaml as it should be :

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    [1 line...]
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
    {
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/*.yaml');
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');

        if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.yaml')) {
            $container->import('../config/{services}.yaml');
            $container->import('../config/{services}_'.$this->environment.'.yaml');
        } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.php')) {
            (require $path)($container->withPath($path), $this);
        }
    }
    [14 lines...]
```

Comment: Maybe your Kernel class is not loading `services.yaml`? Also, is indentation in Yaml correct? Here seems to be missing `services` key and indentation to be wrong

Comment: @Justinas I have correct indentation in my question. But this indentation problem is not present in my file. Also i have add services key here that I've forget when copy/paste it. I have provide ``Kernel`` class

Comment: Remove `config/services_dev.yaml`. Do you have `_defaults: autowire: true autoconfigure: true` in `config/services.yaml`?

Comment: So is it working now?  I see "Now it work !" in your question.  Remember that using services_dev.yaml is extremely rare in most cases.  And also remember that loading services and loading package config files really are two different things.  Don't confuse the two.

Comment: @Leprechaun Yes i have ``_defaults`` as you say. I didn't provide it into the code because this is default configuration of a Symfony project.
@Cerad It is working only if i copy paste it into my  ``services_dev.yaml`` But I don't want to copy paste EVERY single configuration for each services for each environment.

I want thing work as it should be : https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/configuration/configuration_organization.html

Comment: Did you try removing `config/services_dev.yaml`? As @Cerad already mentioned "extremely rare in most cases" and I also don't see a reason why you want to have it.

Comment: Well... it work if i remove the ``services`` section for the ``services_dev.yaml`` Good thing to know ! I think this one is solved ! Thank you

Comment: Store parameters in `.env` files. You don't need separate `services.yaml` for this.

Comment: @Leprechaun yes that's true but I didn't want to poluate ``.env`` file, it seams not a good idea to define variable in here... I don't know i prefer the idea that parameter is manage into ``config/`` directory

Comment: Then keep `parameters:` block and just try to remove `services:` part from `services_dev.yaml`. Theoretically is will override only parameters and reuse service definitions from `services.yaml`.

Comment: Consider posting your test project to a github repo and providing the link.  I made a quick test project and it all worked as expected.  I suspect you have more going on.  What you are trying to do is a very very very basic configuration.  No reason it should not work out of the box.  Maybe you are trying to have two different configurations?  One specifically for dev and one for production?

Comment: @Cerad No no it is working now I have remove ``services`` from ``services_dev.yaml`` and now it is ok !

Comment: But why have a services_dev.yaml file in the first place?  If services.yaml and services_dev.yaml both have auto wire enabled then they will both try to wire the same service and the service.yaml wiring will end up taking priority.  That is probably what happened in your original setup.  Don't user services_dev.yaml unless you have a very good reason.  If you just want different env variables then use something like .env.dev and .env.prod

Comment: Yes this was the problem, and I have use ``services_dev.yaml`` because I'm new to Symfony and I have made a mistake ! That's why I have ask for help. I was thinking that ``services_env.yaml`` was used to defined global parameter which doesn't change inside of an environment. That's why I have set some environment specific parameters inside of those kind of files.

Answer (score -1):

Why you configure param xx_id as int in your yml file ? In your service you type-hinted id as string !